# (set) keyword in swift

Tags: swift

I was recently browsing through the [DemoBots](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/DemoBots/Introduction/Intro.html) example from Apple and I came across:

```
/// The scene that is currently being presented.
private (set) var currentSceneMetadata: SceneMetadata?
```

What exactly does `(set)` do and what other options (if any) are available here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means only setter is private. So **currentSceneMetadata** access for *get* is the default--which is internal-- but that of *set* is private. So it can only be changed from within the same source file.

Link to confirm: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html

**EDIT**: You could even do something like this:

```
public private (set) var name: String
```

which means name's access level for *setter* is **private** and for *getter* is **public**.